# Why Duplicate Social Post appearing when a new case is created in Social Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio, socialpost

Whenever first time Social post is created, it is appearing twice on Case. This is happening only when new Social Post and Case is created.

After that, if any social post is coming then it is appearing once.

Also, I checked in backend, there is only single record for social post but on UI it is posted twice on Case under Feed Section

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to some triggers that are causing multiple updates on the Case or Social Post.  The Social Post you see on the Case feed is actual a separate feed item.